# How to build sails.js offline documentation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github, sails.js

I want to use offline sails.js documentation in my system.

The documentation of sails.js is maintained at the link [Sails.js Documentation](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs).

As they mention there, they use [doc-templater](https://github.com/uncletammy/doc-templater) to build the documentation. I tried the code below in the node REPL.

```js
require('doc-templater')().build({
  remote: 'git@github.com:balderdashy/sails.git',
  remoteSubPath: '',
  cachePath: '/code/sandbox/doctemplatertest/foo/bar/cache/',
  htmlDirPath: '/code/sandbox/doctemplatertest/foo/bar/html',
  jsMenuPath: '/code/sandbox/doctemplatertest/foo/bar.jsmenu'
}, function (e,r) {
  if (e) {console.log('ERROR:\n',require('util').inspect(e, false, null));}
  else console.log('RESULT:\n',require('util').inspect(r, false, null));
});`
```

But it is not working; I'm getting this result:

```
RESULT: 
[]
undefined
```

Can anyone please show the way it works.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they never got that module quite working:
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/issues/523#issuecomment-136823015

Alternatively you can clone the git repo of the documentation website:
https://github.com/balderdashy/www.sailsjs.org

And run it with sails?